# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, java-8

`Predicate` é uma interface funcional que permite testar objetos de um determinado
tipo. Dado um `Predicate`, o `removeIf` vai remover todos os elementos
que devolverem true para esse predicado.

Ao tentar usa o método `removeIf()`, para fazer teste em uma lista que recebe um Predicate, estou tendo a exceção citada no titulo, alguém sabe o por que ?

Código:

```
Predicate<Usuario> predicado = new Predicate<Usuario>() {
        public boolean test(Usuario u) {
            return u.getPontos() > 160;
        }
};


List<Usuario> lista = Arrays.asList(usuario,usuario1, usuario2, usuario3);
lista.removeIf(predicado);
lista.forEach(u -> System.out.println(u));
```

Porem quando faço desta maneira ele imprimir sem erro:

```
Predicate<Usuario> predicado = new Predicate<Usuario>() {
    public boolean test(Usuario u) {
        return u.getPontos() > 160;
    }
};

List<Usuario> lista = new ArrayList<Usuario>();


lista.add(usuario2);
lista.add(usuario3);
lista.add(usuario1);
lista.add(usuario);
lista.removeIf(predicado);
lista.forEach(u -> System.out.println(u));
```

Alguem sabe o por que da exceção lançada, quando passo os usuario dentro do :

```
Arrays.asList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que `Arrays.asList` retorna uma lista de tamanho fixo. Você está tentando modificar essa lista, então recebe a exceção.

A [documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) chama isso de "ponte entre APIs de coleções e de arrays". O motivo para esse comportamento provavelmente é que eles acharam importante ter a propriedade de que o mesmo vetor passado para a função compusesse os dados da lista gerada. Questão de desempenho, imagino. É uma boa justificativa, mas esse nome causa muita confusão.

Java não tem problemas em chamar uma classe de `BufferedInputStream` mas não chamou esse método de `wrapInAList` ou algo assim. Vai entender...

Comment: No caso Arrays.asList é imutavel ? e ArrayList<>() nao ?

Comment: Não é imutável, mas não pode mudar de tamanho (pode mudar o valor dos elementos). `ArrayList` é uma `List` "normal", que permite remoção normalmente.

Comment: Obrigado entende cara, valeu pela força!

Answer (score -1):

Se vc precisar usar o Arrays.asList() de qualquer jeito, então vc pode fazer dessa forma para evitar o erro.
List list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList())